# How to access internal dashboards in Cube?

Tags: dashboard, cube, square, cubism.js

I am currently playing around with Cube . I have been able to send events to an evaluator and can query these via HTTP GET.

How do I go about making a customized dashboard to visualize the events/queries? I saw this website http://corner.squareup.com/2011/09/cube.html has a video for creating a "dashboard in 60 seconds" but I do not know where to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.
The last version of Cube on GitHub to have the fat, non-static, non-Cubism client side from the video was 
[e51cd376](https://github.com/square/cube/tree/e51cd376c36325aacd83c7b4e42894b1be80a429).

If you have a clone of the current repository use:

```
git reset --hard e51cd376
```

Then start your mongodb, and `node evaluator`.
The mongodb database format does not seem to have substantially changed.

You could: at least to some extent, use the current collector, dump the database into a duplicated db, or *maybe* run the two separate versions of cube evaluators side-by-side, depending on your dashboarding needs.

Uglier but a bit quicker for mashing around with the queries.

Comment: [cubeboard](https://github.com/jlauman/cubeboard) is another fork that is based around that version of Cube's board.